# Get data from multiple SELECT sub-queries for reporting from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to achieve is to create one complex query consisting of a few sub-queries.  The idea is to give it to a business person to run on a weekly basis to pull reporting data.

The effect would be similar to the query below, where all data from many tables are displayed in one result.

```
select * from table1, table2, table3
```

So I need something like, but it's not working.

```
select 
    (select * from   table1 where ...... ) as table1,
    (select * from   table2 where....... ) as table2
```

Manually, I could run the sub-queries separately, then manually append the results into one big excel sheet.  But I want to make it easier for the business person to do this, and minimize errors.

Is this possible in MySQL?

The reason for this is I'm converting a legacy Oracle PIVOT SQL statements into the MySQL equivalence, and the sub-queries are pretty complex.

I can provide the Oracle SQL if needed.

Much appreciated as always.

Comment: the oracle sql would indeed help.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After some fiddling around:

```
select * from
    (select * from   table1 where survey_user_id=4 ) as T1
    ,
    (select * from   table2 where survey_field_type_id=100 ) as T2
    ,
    (select * from table3  )  as T3
```

Comment: Something weird. I have 31 rows and I try to use your query. It returns to me 961 rows (31 x 31)....

Answer (score 12):

If i understand you correctly you just need UNION :D

```
(SELECT column1 AS name1, column2 AS name2 FROM table1 WHERE ...... )
UNION
(SELECT column3 AS name1, column4 AS name2 FROM table2 WHERE ...... )
UNION
....
```

As mentioned bellow in comment,
columns need to have the same name (you can use aliases for it) and stay in the same order.

Comment: Provided that the columns are the same order and data types, otherwise it would choke.

Comment: A union will append each query's results to the result set and with the assumption that the columns align.  With the solution from @user1775967, columns can be selected from any of the queries with the assumption that the rows are aligned.

Answer (score 2):

```
select main.*,
(select col from tbl1 where tbl1.id=main.id) as col1,
(select col from tbl2 where tbl2.id=main.id) as col2,
(select col from tbl3 where tbl3.id=main.id) as col3
from master as main
```

Comment: When answering a question, please add some explanation as to what your doing or why it solves the original question.

Comment: Except for some differently named columns, I do not see how this differs from accepted answer's solution.